# RStudio tab functionality working differently

Tags: r, rstudio

On my desktop computer, `tab` quickly moves a comment or command across over 4 spaces in rapid succession. On my laptop, `tab` brings up a message that says "(No matches)", then when I hit `tab` again, it moves 4 spaces, then another message, then another 4 spaces. I cannot quickly move text to the right. I imagine this is a setting I can turn on and off but I cannot figure it out.
[image]

I am using 0.99.903

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Odds are you need to tweak two settings:

- Insert spaces for tab
- Use tab for multiline autocompletions

You can find each in the `Global Options` pane:

[image]

[image]

Comment: It seems to only be a problem when moving a comment or command.

Comment: Can you update your question with a reproducible example? What is the code you're trying to edit, and what are you seeing? Also, what version of RStudio?

Comment: I added a picture

Comment: Thanks -- I believe unchecking the 'Use tab for multiline autocompletions' preference will give you the expected behavior here.

Comment: Indeed it does. Thank you!